# handling JSON in php and mysql

Tags: php, json

I try to write a webhook to store data to my own database. data is coming through JSON from a different website.

Data format from source website:
[screen shot for json format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KF8S.png)

how can I handle this json in php? I already tried json_decode but didn't seem to work!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at the older questions and try removing the padding.

Comment: already checked the older questions, for some reason nothing is working for me. I work in humanitarian organization and need to deliver a project on time. thanks anyway